# Least price upcs for products by store wise and by Global from a price table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what is my price table looks like

```
Product_id prod_upc    str_nbr  Price
prod110010 4122067755  12       1.22
prod110010 4122067755  21       2.88
prod110010 4122063030  21       3.88
prod110010 4122063030  12       2.88
prod110010 4122063031  12       2.88
prod110010 4122063031  21       4.88
```

I have two requirements to solve

1. Get the least priced UPC for all Products across all the store ? based on the above data the output should be

   ```
   prod110010  4122067755  12      1.22
   ```
2. Get the least priced upc for all Products in each store ? based on the above data the output should be

   ```
   prod110010  4122067755  12      1.22
   prod110010  4122067755  21      2.88
   ```

I tried may inner queries but nothing worked, any SQL experts here please help.

My query for the store specific is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.product_id, t.prod_upc,t.str_nbr, t.MINVALUE 
  FROM ( SELECT dpc.product_id, hpd.prod_upc, str_nbr
              , MIN(hpd.curr_retl_prc) OVER 
                 (PARTITION BY dpc.product_id) MINVALUE 
           FROM prc_dta ) AS T
```

and for the global:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.product_id, t.prod_upc, t.str_nbr, t.MINVALUE 
  FROM ( SELECT dpc.product_id, hpd.prod_upc, hpd.str_nbr
              , MIN(hpd.curr_retl_prc) OVER 
                    (PARTITION BY dpc.product_id,hpd.str_nbr) MINVALUE 
           FROM prc_dta) AS T
```

Comment: Please show the code you tried and explain how it failed.

Comment: Please edit your post to add that information (and take care with the formatting). There's an "edit" link just under the tags for that.

Comment: Please **edit your question**, add your queries to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
This query to get min price upc row : 

    select top 1 Product_id,prod_upc,str_nbr,Price from tbl where prod_upc=(select top 1 min(prod_upc) from tb1 ) order by Price asc

This query get all row of min price of upc:

select Product_id,prod_upc,str_nbr,Price from tbl where prod_upc=(select top 1 min(prod_upc) from tb1 ) order by Price asc
```

Comment: I couldnt understand this where condition where prod_upc=(select top 1 min(prod)_upc from tb1    prod_upc is the upc column in my table

Comment: The subquery is incorrectly going for MIN(prod_upc) when it should be returning the UPC associated with MIN(price)

Comment: I want to fetch the min priced upc but not Min of UPC values.... but the inner query looks the otherway

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ranked (Product_id, prod_upc, str_nbr, Price, pricerank)
AS ( SELECT Product_id, prod_upc, str_nbr, Price,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY str_nbr ORDER BY Price ) AS pricerank
    FROM tbl
   )
SELECT Product_id, prod_upc, str_nbr, Price FROM ranked WHERE pricerank = 1
```

Comment: This is giving me the rows where the min of all products price is matching , lets say if min price value in the table is 1.2 this is giving me the rows where the price value is 1.2.... but my intetion is to get the min price rows for every product and for every product in every store